# Boolean in Racket

Tags: racket

I run the test and there is always one test cannot pass. I tried every permutation. Is there an easier way like maybe try not returning a simple boolean, maybe the return depends on the input(s)?

Here are my codes:

```
(check-expect (same? #true #true) #true)
(check-expect (same? #false #false) #true)
(check-expect (same? #true #false) #false)

(define (same? b1 b2)
 (cond
    [ b1 #t ]
    [ b2 #f ]
    [else #t]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `same?` definition is wrong. To pass all test cases, you can use [`equal?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Equality.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._equal%7E3f%29%29):

```
(define same? equal?) ; <-- some languages, e.g. BSL don't allow this way

(define (same? b1 b2)
  (equal? b1 b2))
```

or, if you aren't allowed to use `equal?`, you can write something like this:

```
(define (same? b1 b2)
  (if b1 (if b2 #true #false)
      (if b2 #false #true)))
```

(In this solution, I expect `b1` and `b2` to be boolean values and nothing else.)

Comment: What if it's like (check-expect (same? #true #true) #false)?

Comment: So, you want function which behaves like this `(check-expect (same? #true #true) #false)`, `(check-expect (same? #false #false) #true)` , `(check-expect (same? #true #false) #false)`?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about different conditions in boolean.

Comment: That's logical NOR / Peirce's arrow. `(define (nor b1 b2) (not (or b1 b2)))` or `(define (nor b1 b2) (if b1 #false (if b2 #false #true)))`